# UK Transit Visa for my daugther

Tags: visas, uk, transit, peruvian-citizens

I'm traveling with my wife and 5 years old daughter to Sweden, and I bougth flight tickets (one way) for each one of us, from Chicago ORD to London Gatwick LGW, and then another tickets from London Gatwick LGW to Gothemburg GOT. These are the same airport, the same airline and the same day, but I was told that still I need a transit visa to check out and check in our bags because I need to go throught UK border control. My question is, do I need to apply for a Transit Visa for each one of us? how does my daughter's visa must be applied? Thank you.

Comment: "I was told that ... I need a transit visa" -- who told you this? Are you sure they were right?

Comment: What is your citizenship? US citizens don't need a visa to enter Britain.

Comment: @jrivam If you do need a transit visa(s) you must apply online https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa The process and the fee is the same for adults and children.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I need to go throught UK border control, thats why I need a Transit Visa.

Comment: @ReddHerring I'm peruvian. We do have a US visa, but we are not US citizens.

Comment: @Traveller thank you, I was not sure about it, because when I was applying for my child, the process looked the same as for myself :)